# How to look up a certain item in a specific row

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

I have the following code that reads/prints rows of info read directly from a spreadsheet:

```
in_path = connector.GetWorksheetDataWithId(worksheet_id)

# Simple test print

for item in in_path:
    print item
```

Multiple rows in the following format are printed:

```
{'_chk2m': 'Name1@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'PaulDu', '_cokwr': '005C0000003yL'}
{'_chk2m': 'Name2@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'Jeanell', '_cokwr': '005C0000003we'}
{'_chk2m': 'Name3@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'Twanna', '_cokwr': '005C0000004tB'}
{'_chk2m': 'Name4@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'JaneyD', '_cokwr': '005C0000003xJ}
{'_chk2m': 'Name5@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'Charlot', '_cokwr': '005C0000003yS}
{'_chk2m': 'Name6@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'Janessa', '_cokwr': '005C0000004pE'}
{'_chk2m': 'Name7@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'Matilda', '_cokwr': '005C000  0003xK'}
{'_chk2m': 'Name8@domain.com', '_cn6ca': 'ChloeR', '_cokwr': '005C00000040h'}
```

I am attempting to have the user submit the user Alias (2nd Item in the row, for example, 'PaulDu') and have the ID # returned (the 3rd item in the row)

I tried something like this:

```
def dict_test(in_path):
    user_alias = raw_input("Please enter User Alias: ")
    for row in in_path:

        if (user_alias in elt for elt in row):
            return user_alias
            print row

dict_test(in_path)
```

And entered "PaulDu" but couldn't successfully print any row. Also, how would I then call the email from the now identified row?

---

EDIT:

Final working code:

```
in_path = connector.GetWorksheetDataWithId(worksheet_id)

def dict_test(in_path):
    user_alias = raw_input("Please enter User Alias: ")
    data = []
    for row in in_path:

        #if any(user_alias in row[elt] for elt in row):
        #if any(user_alias in value for key, value in row.items()):
        if user_alias in row.values():
            print row


    for row in in_path:
        if user_alias == row['_cn6ca']:
                email = row['_chk2m']
                print email
                return email

dict_test(in_path)
```

Comment: Please post actual text that can be copied and pasted, not screenshots.

Comment: Sorry, should be fixed.

Comment: Your edited version has multiple `SyntaxError`s in it. Can you actually copy and paste it, instead of typing something sort of close that isn't actually evaluatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, before you even get to searching the file…

The name `in_path` implies that it's a pathname. If so, this line:

```
for row in in_path:
```

… is just going to loop over the characters of that pathname, not the contents of the file at that name. If you want to read a file, you have to `open` it. Like this:

```
with open(in_path) as in_file:
    for row in in_file:
```

A first step in debugging any problem like this is to `print` out the intermediate values. If you `print`ed each `row`, it would be immediately obvious why this wasn't working.

---

Next, there are a few problems with this line:

```
if (user_alias in elt for elt in row):
```

First, `row` appears to be a `dict`, which means that `for elt in row` will give you its keys, but you're trying to search in its values.

Second, you're checking the truth value of a generator, which is always true, when you wanted to check whether any of the elements in the generator are true. For that, use the [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function.

What you probably wanted was something like one of the following:

```
if any(user_alias in row[elt] for elt in row):
if any(user_alias in value for key, value in row.items()):
```

Also, are you really looking for substrings? Your example is an exact match, and from your description, that sounds more reasonable. In which case, you can just write:

```
if user_alias in row.values():
```

---

Meanwhile:

> Also, how would I then call the email from the now identified row?

Well, your code implies that you don't know the keys, which means the only thing you can possibly do is go through the values in the found row and heuristically find the one that looks most like an email address.

If you *do* know the keys, this is a lot easier:

```
if user_alias == row['_cn6ca']:
    email = row['_chk2m']
```

Comment: I tried both of the if any statements you posted, but my test print didn't print any rows. I'm assuming this means no rows were successfully looked up after entering PaulDu ?

Comment: @gigawatts: Possibly. But it's hard to tell until you give us usable data. [Here](http://pastebin.com/08xkLgqC) I've fixed it up to something usable, tested, and successfully found a row with my code. Meanwhile, see the edited version for a bigger problem you may be running into before you even get this far.

Comment: Also, at your end comment, thats my main challenge. The user won't know the keys, they'll just have the User Alias as an input and expect  the email to be looked up. But since the key for each type of information is the same, I'm assuming your heuristic method will work

Comment: The _user_ doesn't have to know the keys. If they're always the same, and _you_ know the keys, you can bake them into your script, without having to show them to the end user.

Comment: That makes sense. I've successfully lookup ep/printed the target row, but the last 2 lines of code in your answer keep giving me: "IndentationError: expected an indented block", always on the line that email= row[...] is on

Comment: @gigawatts: As you can see from above, the second line _is_ an indented block. So you've gotten the indentation wrong when copying and pasting. If this isn't immediately visible, you're probably using an editor that lets you mix tabs and spaces, in which case… don't do that.

Comment: Sorry, noob mistake, mixing spaces and tabs. Thanks for all the help, final working code is posted in edit above. What editor would you suggest? I use textwrangler...

Comment: @gigawatts: Well, I use Aquamacs, which is perfect if you have decades of emacs experience and also decades of Mac experience, but I'm guessing anyone who falls into that category is already using Aquamacs… I suspect TextWrangler can be configured to always use spaces (in Python mode, or globally), but I haven't used it in a long time, so I can't say any more than that.

Answer (score 0):

The items of `in_path` are dictionaries? In that case you can use the dictionary syntax:

```
def dict_test(in_path):
    user_alias = raw_input("Please enter User Alias: ")
    for row in in_path:
        if row['_cn6ca'] == user_alias:
            print row
            return row['_cokwr']
```

`return` will immediately quit the function, so if you want to display something, you must put the `print` before.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that? (Returning the matched row, from which you can extract any field you need, assuming you know the keys.)

```
   def dict_test(in_path):
        user_alias = raw_input("Please enter User Alias: ")
        for row in in_path:
            if (row['_cn6ca'] == user_alias ):
                return row

    my_row = dict_test(in_path)
    id = my_row['_cokwr']
    email = my_row['_chk2m']
```